# Can I show $\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n} \leq 1$ by induction?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, induction

It is known that $a_{n+1} > a_n$. I tried to prove

$$\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n} \leq 1$$
via induction.

Base case: $a_0 = \frac{1}{0+1} = 1 \leq 1$

Inductive step: assume $a_n \leq 1$, prove $a_{n+1} \leq 1$.

$a_n = \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n} \leq 1$
$\frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{2n+2} \leq 1-\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{2n+2}$

But $-\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{2n+2}$ is positive, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Normally, the inductive step would involve a change on the right hand side, but in this case, it remains the same. Makes me wonder if induction is even the correct approach?

Comment: There are $n$ terms, each $\le \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result is "obvious." There are $n$ terms in the sum, each $\le \frac{1}{n+1}$. So the sum is $\le \frac{n}{n+1}$, which is $\lt 1$.

If we, unreasonably, want to prove the result by induction, we run into the problem mentioned in the OP.  The solution is to **strengthen** the induction hypothesis. We prove by induction that our sum is $\le \frac{n}{n+1}$.

So suppose we know that for a particular $k$ we have
$$\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2k}\le \frac{k}{k+1}.\tag{1}$$
We want to show that
$$\frac{1}{k+2}+\frac{1}{k+3}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{2k+1}+\frac{1}{2k+2}\le \frac{k+1}{k+2}.\tag{2}$$
Now if we use the induction hypothesis (1) and play a bit with inequalities, we can prove (2).

Comment: Please note I had a typo in (2), that I managed to fix within the 5 minute window.

Comment: As always, very well done.  Concise, complete, and simple! +1

Comment: In fixing the typo in (2) I introduced one in (1). Now fixed!

Answer (score -2):

According to Wolfram Alpha, this series is equivalent to $ \psi^{(0)}(2n+1)-\psi^{(0)}(n+1)$ where $ \psi^{(0)}(x)$ is the $n^{th}$ derivative of the digamma function. Using this, you could show the continuity for the function for values of $n > 0$, show that the limit as n approaches infinity is $log(2)$ (easily proven), and show that the function is continuously increases (by showing derivative is positive for $n>0$?)

**Note that this actually shows that the series is always $< log(2)$, a stronger statement than that given by the induction argument.**